# Implicit Casting Broken Through Out Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems that there may be a conflict somewhere within my app causing implicit cast conversions of classes living in App_Code to stop working.

Here is an example of an exception:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'ABC.Edu.CourseCatalog.Subject' to 'ABC.Edu.Admin.Subject'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 76:                 } Line 77:  Line 78:                 Subject
>   primarySubject =
>   SubjectHelper.GetPrimarySubjectForContent(courseContentID); Line 79: 
>   Line 80:                 if (primarySubject != null &&
>   subjectContentID == primarySubject.ContentId)
>
> Source File: e:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\admin\PrimarySubjects.aspx.cs
>   Line: 78

To solve this I had to explicitly cast the Subject class cast found on Line 78 in the source error above.

The strange thing is, this just started to randomly happen one day to a lot of my casts through out the app. Although it appears to me as 'randomly', I am sure there is a reason for it but I am unable to determine what it is.

**Question:** What would cause implicit class type conversions to stop working one day?

Comment: make sure you dont write `Subject` when you want to use that class. instead fully qualify it with `ABC.Edu.CourseCatalog.Subject` or `ABC.Edu.Admin.Subject`. two class with same names can make ambiguous problem

Comment: I do not have a class named ABC.Edu.Admin.Subject and I am not sure why it is trying to change it to the Admin namespace. The class is being called from a folder called Admin though...